# An expression of a check constraint contains disallowed function

Tags: mysql

```
create table ships
(
name   varchar(6) not null primary key,
class  varchar(6) null,
launched date     null
); 
        
create table battles
(
name varchar(6) null,
date date       null,
CONSTRAINT 
fk foreign key battles(name) references ships(name) 
);
            
create function test.getShipLaunchedDate(shipName varchar(255)) returns DATE DETERMINISTIC
begin
return (select launched from ships where name=shipName);
end;
            
select test.get_Ships_launched_Function('t1');
            
select test.get_Battles_date_Function('b1');
            
alter table battles add constraint check (date<test.getShipLaunchedDate(name));
```

[HY000][3814] An expression of a check constraint 'checkBattleShipDate' contains disallowed function: getShipLaunchedDate
I realize why it doesn't work but is there a way to have a function in a check constraint?

Comment: Even if it would work, shouldn't the condition be `date>test.getShipLaunchedDate(name)` to indicate, that the battle should have placed *after* it was launched?

Answer (score 1):

You can extends the foreign key from `ships(name)` to `ships(name, launched)`. That way you are applying the following constrains in your database:

- You can't change the `launched` date anymore when you have one row in the `battle` table referencing the row from the `ships` table (due to foreign key constraints).
- You have "access" to the `launched` date in your `battle` table.

With that the `CHECK` can just be `CHECK(battledate >= launcheddate)`. See the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE ships
(
    name   varchar(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    launched date     NULL,
    class  varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    
    UNIQUE (name, launched)
);

CREATE TABLE battles
(
    name varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    launcheddate date NOT NULL,
    battledate date       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (name, launcheddate) REFERENCES ships(name, launched),
    
    CHECK (battledate >= launcheddate)
);
```

With these tables you can run the following `INSERT` statements with the expected result:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ships(name, launched, class)
       VALUES ('Dummy', '2020-04-24', 'xyz');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO battles(name, launcheddate, battledate)
       VALUES ('Dummy', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-25');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO battles(name, launcheddate, battledate)
       VALUES ('Dummy', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-23');
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'battles_chk_1' is violated.
```

Comment: launcheddate refers to the date the ship was launched or manufactured. it's kind of weird to have it in another table where it doesn't belong

Comment: @Ghost It is not the "original" storage for the launcheddate, the value is still coming from the `ships` table, where it should be stored semantically. With the `CHECK` statement the launcheddate value has to come somehow to the `battles` table, which is solved by using it as a foreign key.